# converting thread to multiprocess pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

basically i have a thread code right now but i wish to try to convert to multiprocessing pool for testing the performance

```
user_dict = {
            'users': [
                {
                    'username': 'test1',
                    'password': 'opop1',
                },
                {
                    'username': 'test2',
                    'password': 'opop2',
                }
            ]
        }

        thread_list = []
        for user in user_dict['users']:

            ct = threading.Thread(
                target=task,
                args=(
                    some_object,
                    some_other_object,
                    another_object,
                    user['username'],
                    user['password']
                )
            )
        ct.start()
        thread_list.append(ct)

        for thread in thread_list:
            thread.join()
```

something basic, my task function will do some login base on each user's username and password and proceed to assign some information to call an api endpoint to fetch data and write into a json file.

but i have no idea how to convert this into multiprocessing pool as i am not sure how to pass my user_dict and other objects information required for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Pool` and feed it with your function and arguments in a list with `starmap`. With arguments reduced to usr/pwd:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

user_dict = {
            'users': [
                {
                    'username': 'test1',
                    'password': 'opop1',
                },
                {
                    'username': 'test2',
                    'password': 'opop2',
                }
            ]
        }

def task(usr, pwd):
    print(usr, pwd, sep=", ")
    return (usr,pwd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=len(user_dict['users']))
    results = pool.starmap(task, [tuple(el.values()) for el in user_dict['users']])
```

`results` contains all returned values for each pool member:

```
[('test1', 'opop1'), ('test2', 'opop2')]
```

Comment: what if my task method need to pass more parameters to it such as objects, def task(usr, pwd, any_object1, any_object2) ?

Comment: if the remaining arguments are repeating, you can simply add them while building your argument list: `args = [list(el.values()) + [any_object1, any_object2] for el in user_dict['users']]`